# For What Abelian groups $A$ Does There Exist a Short Exact Seqeuence $0\to \mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z}\to A\to \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\to 0$.

Tags: abelian-groups, exact-sequence

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$

> **Question:** Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers. What are all the abelian groups $A$ such that there is a short exact sequence $0\to \mathbb Z/p^m\mathbb Z\to A\to \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z\to 0$.

It is clear that any such abelian group $A$ has cardinality $p^{m+n}$. Thus by Fundamental Theore of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups we have $A\cong \Z/p^{k_1}\Z\oplus \cdots\oplus \Z/p^{k_r}\Z$ for some $k_1\leq \cdots \leq k_r$. Also, since $A$ contains a copy of $\Z/p^m\Z$, a cyclic group of order $p^m$, we must have $k_r\geq m$. I am unable to see what to do next.

Also, I am particularly interested in the solution given [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~moller/f03/algtop/opg/S2.1.pdf) in the form of *Proposition 0.1* on pg 2.
On the first line of the solution it uses a notion of "pull-back" which I do not understand. Can somebody shed some light on this solution?

Comment: Your title is not very useful.

Comment: The link you provide does not lead anywhere.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi I am sorry. I got busy midway typing the title and then didn't observe that it was incomplete.

Comment: @BenS. Fixed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you reference is unnecessarily sophisticated...but at least it tells you the answer.

You have already found two properties that any such group $A$ must have:

1) $A$ has order $p^{m+n}$.  In particular, it is a commutative $p$-group.
2) $A$ has an element of order $p^m$.

You need one more property:

3) $A$ can be generated by two elements.

Thus in your appeal to the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups you know you can take $r \leq 2$.  The two extreme cases are a cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/p^{m+n}\mathbb{Z}$ and the group $\mathbb{Z}/p^m \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$.  You should be able to check that these groups and "everything in between" can actually occur.